# Avoid export error for AWS CloudFront Function and doing unit tests

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cloudfront-functions

How can I avoid this error: "The CloudFront function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or could not run. SyntaxError: Illegal export statement", and still be able to unit test a function?

### Example function for CloudFront function

```js
//myfun.js

function handler (event) {
   return event.request;
}
```

Test code for jest

```js
const handler = require('./myfun.js');

test('handler runs', () => {
  expect(handler({request: {}})
  ).toStrictEqual({});

});
```

Running `jest`, would generate an error like : `TypeError: rewrite is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to limitations in CloudFront functions [runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-javascript-runtime-features.html), it is not possible at the moment to run functions with `export` and other mechanisms.

A quick workaround is to avoid deploying the code from file and read it with an IaC tool that allows preprocessing, eg: cdk.

### Example in python [cdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront/Function.html)

Where the extra line was added at the end of `myfun.js`

```js
...

module.exports = handler;
```

And the CDK code to create the CFN Function resource is:

```py
CF_FUNCTION_FILE = "./myfun.js"

output = []
with open(CF_FUNCTION_FILE) as f:
  output += f.readlines()[:-1]  # Skip last line

aws_cloudfront.Function(
  self, "myCFfun",
  code=aws_cloudfront.FunctionCode.from_inline("\n".join(output))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your myfun.js

// myfun.js

```
-------

if(console.error) {
   module.exports = handler;
}
```

`console.error` is undefined in cloudfront function, hence the `if(console.error)` check would ensure that `module.exports` line only runs in your test and your handler is successfully exported for testing.